# How to use laravel model inside a simple php file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a function that I can call inside controllers so I tought about creating a .php file in App folder and use it inside the controller, but how do I write inside that file like in a controller.

Example contents of the file:

```
<?php

function sendNotification(icon, text, userID)
{


}

?>
```

Do I just write like this:?

```
<?php

    function sendNotification(icon, text, userID)
    {
      $var = new Notifications;
      $var->notificationText = "string";
      $var->save();

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so that shouldn't be a problem.. you controllers are basically nothing but classes written in plain php file only. so you can create your own too.

So now you can either create a file having your function or a file having a class that has your function. lets take first approach.

1. so for now simply create a file say helper.php within your
   `app/<your directory name>` directory.
2. add Content to your file say function [or class] which uses you model.
3. Add the `use` statement at top for your `model` in this file.
4. Tell composer about your file by editing your `composer.json` file as

   "files": [
               "app/"
   ]
5. call `composer-dumpautoload` to generate autoloader for you.
6. To use your function/class in some file call function.

eg.
    1) app\helper.php

```
    <?php
    use App\User;

    function helper()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        dd($user);
    }
```

2) app\controller\testController.php

```
function test()
  {
   dd(helper());
  }
```

3) composer.json

```
"files" : [
            "app\\helper.php"
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

**1** Within your `app/Http` directory, create a helpers.php file and add your functions.

**2** Within `composer.json`, in the autoload block, add

`"files":["app/Http/helpers.php"]`.

**3** Run `composer dump-autoload.`

In `helpers.php` add your function:

```
<?php
    /**
     * @param $icon
     * @param $text
     * @param $userID
     */
    function sendNotification($icon, $text, $userID)
    {
        $var                   = new \App\Notifications();
        $var->notificationText = "string";
        $var->save();
    }
?>
```

Then simply you can call your function in controllers/ or anywhere in your laravel app `sendNotification($icon, $text, $userId)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the function at the bottom. Example:

```
public function myAwesomeFunction(){
    $this->helperFunction();
}


private function helperFunction(){
    echo "I'm a helper function";
}
```

As @Leo's has advised you you can create a file called `helpers.php` and include it in your `Controller` to leave everything organized.